# TLS configration on AMAZON LINUX 1 aint working

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tls1.2, amazon-linux

I am trying to extend the Nginx default configuration in AWS Elastic Beanstalk to reject any incoming requests using pre-1.2 TLS by adding config files under ebextensions folder

I want my app that is being built on **Amazon Linux 1** to reject any requests but TLS 1.2 and 1.3.
this is the configuration that I added

file PATH **.ebextentions/01-setTLSConnection.config**

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01-setTLSConnection.conf":
     mode: "000644"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
        server {
            ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        }
```

but this isn't working, could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

STACK: NODEJS built on JavaScript

Comment: Curious but why on AWS linux 1? That's EOL and on maintenance mode till 2023. Why not use AWS linux 2 images?

Comment: @alex067 I have two applications one on AL2 and the old one on AL1. 
I am facing the same issue on both applications. however, I am focusing now on AL1 then will figure something out for AL2

Comment: Do you have a load balancer? You can set the TLS configuration on the load balancer listener directly if so.

Comment: @littleforest I do have loader balancer, however I want the configuration to be on both Nginx and load balancer level